# using ckeditor has error in orchard cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I use orchard cms.I had added ckeditor module in orchard.but when I want to add a blog post I have seen this error :

```
The type or namespace name 'CKEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
in this source ...\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\CKEditor\Views\CKEditor.Config.cshtml
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
Only I have put the ckeditor folder in my modules folder.Modules folder does not have ckeditor folder